# Cluster module issue in Node.js 0.4.12

Tags: node.js

I'm setting up a Vagrant environment to do some work on a project that uses an older version of Node.js. I've been working my way through various hiccups and have reached one that has me a little stuck. The project uses the Cluster module (before it was core, I assume) and when I try to start the Node server, I get this:

```
$ node /vagrant/node/bin/server.js
  info - worker 0 spawned
  info - worker 1 spawned
  info - listening for connections
  info - master started
uncaughtException
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  message: 'Non-socket exists at  /vagrant/node/cluster.repl' }
  warning - kill(SIGKILL)
Error: Non-socket exists at  /vagrant/node/cluster.repl
    at net.js:1054:17
  debug - exit
```

Google doesn't have much to offer unless my Google Fu has been very weak for the last 24 hours.

Here's the code that starts the server:

```
server = cluster(server)
 .use(cluster.repl(root + '/cluster.repl'))
 .use(cluster.stats({connections: true, requests: true}))
 .use(cluster.reload(root))
 .listen(port)
```

Anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: The non core cluster module has continued to evolve along with node, and likely is no longer 0.4.x compatible.  You should try reverting to older versions of it to find the latest version that doesn't break.  What version of cluster are you using?

Comment: You're right, @generalhenry, I should have been more specific. I'm using cluster 0.7.4. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it, and didn't run into any trouble.  `ls /vagrant/node/` does cluster.repl already exist? It sounds like it might just need a `rm /vagrant/node/cluster.repl`

Comment: It does exist. Removing it and restarting the server doesn't appear to help.

Comment: Jumping back in, something has changed. Now I get a `EPERM, Operation not permitted` error. Appears to occur in the `.use(cluster.repl(root + '/cluster.repl'))` line. Perms on `root` are 777.